# How to Post Pojo Class and get Response with Response Boady

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I need to post data whole `JSON` object as `post` in `retrofit` but i need to handle the response with `response body`. actually i created a pojo class for post data but my Response was getting `null` so tell me how to i handle it.

API Post method:

```
@POST("api/default/user-form-update")
Call<ResponseBody> creatPost(
       @Body UserformUpdate userformUpdate
);
```

post Pojo class:

public class UserformUpdate {

```
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("gender")
@Expose
private String gender;
@SerializedName("dob")
@Expose
private String dob;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("role_id")
@Expose
private String roleId;
@SerializedName("role_id_doc")
@Expose
private String roleIdDoc;
@SerializedName("mobile_number")
@Expose
private String mobileNumber;
@SerializedName("device_id")
@Expose
private String deviceId;
@SerializedName("os_id")
@Expose
private String osId;
@SerializedName("country_id")
@Expose
private String countryId;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("profile_picture")
@Expose
private ProfilePicture profilePicture;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getRoleId() {
    return roleId;
}

public void setRoleId(String roleId) {
    this.roleId = roleId;
}

public String getRoleIdDoc() {
    return roleIdDoc;
}

public void setRoleIdDoc(String roleIdDoc) {
    this.roleIdDoc = roleIdDoc;
}

public String getMobileNumber() {
    return mobileNumber;
}

public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
}

public String getDeviceId() {
    return deviceId;
}

public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
}

public String getOsId() {
    return osId;
}

public void setOsId(String osId) {
    this.osId = osId;
}

public String getCountryId() {
    return countryId;
}

public void setCountryId(String countryId) {
    this.countryId = countryId;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public ProfilePicture getProfilePicture() {
    return profilePicture;
}

public void setProfilePicture(ProfilePicture profilePicture) {
    this.profilePicture = profilePicture;
}
```

}

package  com.example.admin.mvp.Post_Request;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ProfilePicture {

```
@SerializedName("file_name")
@Expose
private String fileName;
@SerializedName("file_data")
@Expose
private String fileData;

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public String getFileData() {
    return fileData;
}

public void setFileData(String fileData) {
    this.fileData = fileData;
}
```

}

Activity class:

```
   private void updatedata(){

        ProfilePicture profilePicture1=new ProfilePicture();
        UserformUpdate userformUpdate=new UserformUpdate();
        userformUpdate.setName(firstnameedt.getText().toString());
        userformUpdate.setGender((String) spinnergender.getSelectedItem());
        userformUpdate.setDob(edt_dobedt.getText().toString());
        userformUpdate.setEmail( emailedt.getText().toString());
        userformUpdate.setRoleId("143f37f2-ca38-0ab1-2489-1e47113655fc");
        userformUpdate.setRoleIdDoc("d84daecc-6339-4860-8eef-9dea3b2f3e4e");
        userformUpdate.setMobileNumber(phoneno);
        userformUpdate.setDeviceId(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
        userformUpdate.setOsId("b93a9204-ee21-4cf9-8a94-cf5eeabf7301");
        userformUpdate.setCountryId("15b5ba45-ce8c-4667-a781-a4e8167315ab");
        userformUpdate.setPassword( password.getText().toString());
        userformUpdate.setProfilePicture(profilePicture1);

        profilePicture1.setFileName("jpg");
        profilePicture1.setFileData(encoded);


        Call<ResponseBody> loginCall= jsonPlaceHolderApi.creatPost(userformUpdate);

        loginCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Reree"+response.body()+"/"+call);
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
                 System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>isSuccessful"+response.body());
            }

            }

            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>error"+call);

            }


        });

    }
```

Please tell me how to i get proper response and how i can handle error response also but Am getting null response or `ServerError`

Comment: I advice you to use Volley: https://developer.android.com/training/volley . It is much better and simpler than retrofit.

Comment: i tried volley too but am getting same Server error or Null response on it.

Comment: you can also create pojo class of your response, and pass it instead of passing `ResponseBody`

Comment: Have you tried in POSTMAN and Is it working?